# Which mobile technologies to use for an existing C#/.Net software?

Tags: .net, mobile

I have a software devlopped using Asp.Net MVC and Angular.

I'm looking to develop a mobile version for my software.

Basically, the Mobile Application will call the WebApi.

Comment: Angular has mobile support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of options:

1. You could create native mobile applications (IOS, Android, etc.).
2. Add [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) to your existing application.
3. Another option would be to create a completely new mobile version of the application (create views like `index.mobile.cshtml`) and serve those pages to mobile users.

I would recommend using responsive design, because it is easier to maintain than the others.